# Не работает код Python vk api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

**Если я задал user_id и текст сообщения то всё работает нормально**
`print(vk.messages.send(user_id = 'Здесь id',random_id= "" ,message="Здесь текст"))`

**Если я задал user_id и текст сообщения через переменную то выдаёт ошибку**

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('Логин', 'пароль')
vk_session.auth()

vk = vk_session.get_api()

def sendmessages(usid,textsend):
    print(vk.messages.send(user_id = 'usid',random_id= "" ,message="textsend"))

commands00 = input()
usid = input('Укажите id:')
textsend = input('Укажите текст сообщения:')
if commands00 == ('send'):
    sendmessages(usid,textsend)
```

vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: user_id not integer

Там говорится что `user_id не целое число`,Не понимаю в чём подвох если задаёшь ручками в текстовом редакторе id и текст то всё нормально,если же через переменную то ошибка.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, здесь вы не задаёте значение параметра `user_id` через переменную, а передаёте в параметр строку "usid"

```
vk.messages.send(user_id='usid', random_id='', message='textsend')
```

Исправьте на

```
vk.messages.send(user_id=usid, random_id='', message=textsend)
```

Во-вторых, функция `input` возвращает строку. Если нужно число, то возвращённое значение необходимо преобразовать:

```
sendmessages(int(usid), textsend)
```

P.S. Соблюдайте [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).